# repartition heavily fragmented impala table in impala

Tags: impala

After creating a PARQUET table using a join from a very big table(500m+ rows) and a rather small table(2000+ rows), I'm left with highly partitioned table that can no longer be used in my cluster. I can only do simple select. Order by would fail with memory error. Upon checking the newly created table, I found that it is heavily fragmented (hundreds of files with the size around 1KB each).

I have 2 ways of solving this problem, both of which aren't very ideal for me (complicated):

- read the file using pyspark, repartition and dump into a text, and create a new table using the text file
- create a new text table, and dump all the data from the parquet table into the text table

  - Cat all the text file together into a single text file (i.e. cat command in bash)
  - delete the heavily partitioned text file, and replace it with the new text file created using cat

My question is: Is there a better way to repartition a heavily fragmented table in impala?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can recreate the table in parquet format with new partition.

1. Identify a column(s) on which data is evenly distributed. 500M table can be easily divided in 100 partitions. Pls note, order by within a partition will be fast but over multiple partitions will be slow because it cant use benefit of partitioning. So, be careful while choosing and consider future usage of the table.
2. create an empty table(t1) stored as parquet partitioned by above column.
3. insert into t1  from old table.
   `insert into T1 partition(new_col) select ...,new_col from orig_T1`
4. compute stats T1
5. Drop orig_T1, rename T1 to orig_T1.

Comment: Probably 2&3 can also be done together with create table as select (you can add partitioning there to)

Comment: absolutely. But if it fails to load 500M(like OPs current process), CTAS wont work. OP can do insert in bunch in such scenario.